# web services parameters in angularjs? can't find solution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

I've already tried the other solutions on stackoverflow with no success.

```
app.services.factory('SearchResource', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("https://..../rest/demo/v1/AMID4?auth=demo_full:1", {}, {'query':     {method: 'GET', isArray: false}}); //I've also tried true...        
}]);



app.services.factory('SearchService', ['$q', 'SearchResource', function($q, SearchResource) {
return {
    getAllSearch: function() {
        var delay = $q.defer();
        SearchResource.get(
            function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                delay.resolve(response);
            },
            function (response) {
                delay.reject("can't get search source");
            });
        return delay.promise;
    }
}
}]);
```

I'm using the above code but I get the following error msg:

`Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array`

Now I've tried the solutions to all the other posts and I still can't figure it out...  when I go to network tab --> response (in inspsect element) I can see the result, It must have something to do with the parameters but I'm pretty sure I've tried most formats at this stage... I'm relatively new to angular, am I missing something!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
app.services.factory('SearchResource', [
  '$resource', function ($resource) {

return $resource("https://..../rest/demo/v1/AMID4?auth=demo_full:1", {}, {
  query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true}}); 
}]);
```

Then you are using `SearchResource.get` in your code when you should use `SearchResource.query`, or you can just name it `get`.

You have to define the actions your Resource offer and then use it, as [documented here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) (check bottom of the page for an example).

Also, make sure you don't miss any headers in your `$resource` definition.

Finally, I prefer to use this (in my opinion) cleaner call:

```
SearchResource.query({
  param_id: stuff
}).$promise.then(function(data) {
  return $scope.thing = data;
}, function(e) {
  return console.log(e);
});
```